# What is a correct return type of a GraphQL resolve function?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I faced with an issue that can't resolve on my own. Let's go through it step by step to  point out the problem.

1. I have a mutation `bookAppointment` which returns an `Appointment` object
2. GraphQL schema says that this object should return 4 properties: `id`, `date`, `specialist`, `client`.
3. To follow the GraphQL-style the `specialist` and `client` properties should be a field level resolvers
4. To fetch this objects I need pass `specialistId` to the specialist field level resolver, as well as `clientId` to the client field level resolver.
5. At this point a problem arises.
6. The field level resolvers of `client`, `specialist` expects that root mutation returns fields like `clientId` and `specialistId`. But GraphQL syntax and types that were generated by that syntax doesn't include this props (make sense).
7. How to "extend" the return type of the resolver and its `interface BookAppointmentPayload` to make me and TypeScript happy?

This is my GraphQL schema

```
type Client {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Specialist {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Appointment {
  id: ID!
  date: Date!
  client: Client!
  specialist: Specialist!
}

input BookAppointmentInput {
  date: Date!
  userId: ID!
  specialistId: ID!
}

type BookAppointmentPayload {
  appointment: Appointment!
}

type Mutation {
  bookAppointment(input: BookAppointmentInput!): BookAppointmentPayload!
}
```

This is TypeScript representation of GraphQL schema

```js
interface Client {
  id: string
  name: string
}

interface Specialist {
  id: string
  name: string
}

interface Appointment {
  id: string
  date: Date
  client: Client
  specialist: Specialist
}

interface BookAppointmentPayload {
  appointment: Appointment
}
```

Here I define my resolvers objects

```js
const resolvers = {
  ...
  Mutation: {
    bookAppointment: (parent, args, context, info): BookAppointmentPayload => {
      return {
        appointment: {
          id: '1',
          date: new Date(),
          clientId: '1', // This prop doesn't exist in the TypeScript interface of Appointment, but is required for the field-level resolver of a `client` prop
          specialistId: '1' // This prop doesn't exist int he TypeScript interface of Appointment, but is required for the field-level resolver of a `specialist` prop
        }
      }
    }
  },
  Appointment: {
    client: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      // I need a clientId (e.g. args.clientId) to fetch the client object from the database

      return {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Jhon'
      }
    },
    specialist: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      // I need a specialistId (e.g. args.specialistId) to fetch the specialist object from the database

      return {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Jane'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Solution that come to my mind:

1. Create an interface which represent "actual" return type of the resolver

```js
...
interface Apppointment {
  id: string
  date: Date
  clientId: string // instead of `client: Client`
  specialistId: string // instead of `specialist: Specialist`
}

interface BookAppointmentPayload {
  appointment: Appointment
}
...
```

But this doesn't reflect the GraphQL type. Also tools like [`graphql-generator`](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/) generates the type with actual objects that should be included in the response, not the fields that are going to be used by field-level resolvers. (Am I wrong?)

I would like to know how you're solving such issue?

Comment: This is a common problem and the way that I've solved it in the past is to make the `clientId` and `specialistId` part of the type up front so you have something to "point" to those objects.  If you're against having those in the types, you need to have some underlying structure in whatever the database is holding that does the equivalent, i.e. have a hidden id field to access those references.  

In general you can have these on your `Appointment` interface or have `client` and `specialist` point back to the appointment (this is useful in the case when clients can have many appointments)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "This is a common problem" I couldn't find any mentions about that neither in generator tools nor in graphql doc itself. Putting this props inside GraphQL schema seems like a duplication, where fetching `client` and `specialist` by `appointmentId` from the database is not optimal by performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been investigating this problem quite a lot and have come to the following conclusion.

> Create an interface which represent "actual" return type of the resolver

Most of the time the return type of the resolver function (in JavaScript) doesn't match the type that was declared in the GraphQL SDL

For instance,

```
# GraphQL SDL

type Appointment {
  id: String!
  client: User!
  specialist: Specialist!
}

type BookAppointmentInput { ... }

type BookAppointmentPayload {
  appointment: Appointment!
}

type Mutation {
  bookAppointment: (input: BookAppointmentInput!): BookAppointmentPayload!
}
```

```js
interface AppointmentDatabaseEntity {
  id: string
  clientId: string // In GraphQL-world this prop is an object, but not in JS. Use this prop in field-level resolver to fetch entire object
  specialistId: string // In GraphQL-world this prop is an object, but not in JS. Use this prop in field-level resolver to fetch entire object
}

interface BookAppointmentPayload {
  appointment: AppointmentDatabaseEntity // The return type SHOULDN'T be equal to the GraphQL type (Appointment) 
}

const resolvers = {
  Mutatiuon: {
    bookAppointment: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const appointment = { id: '1', specialistId: '1', clientId: '1' }

      return {
        id: appointment.id,
        specialistId: appointment.specialistId, // Pass this prop to the child resolvers to fetch entire object
        clientId: appointment.clientId // Pass this prop to the child resolvers to fetch entire object
      }
    }
  },
  Appointment: {
    client: (parent: AppointmentDatabaseEntity, args, context, info) => {
      const client = database.getClient(parent.clientId) // Fetching entire object by the property from the parent object
 
      return {
        id: client.id,
        name: client.name,
        email: client.email
      }
    },
    specialist: (parent: AppointmentDatabaseEntity, args, context, info) => {
      const specialist = database.getSpecialist(parent.specialistId) // Fetching entire object by the property from the parent object
 
      return {
        id: specialist.id,
        name: specialist.name,
        email: specialist.email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> But this doesn't reflect the GraphQL type

As far as I understand it is okay

> Also tools like graphql-generator generates the type with actual objects that should be included in the response, not the fields that are going to be used by field-level resolvers. (Am I wrong?)

Yes. I was wrong. The `graphql-generator` has a configuration file that can be used to replace default generated types with the types that you expect your resolvers to return. This option is called `mappers`.

```yaml
plugins
  config:
    mappers:
      User: ./my-models#UserDbObject # User is GraphQL object, which will be replaced with UserDbObject
      Book: ./my-modelsBook # Same rule goes here
```

I don't want to go into details of how to configure it and use, but you can check the links that helped me to understand this

- [Documentation](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/typescript-resolvers) (check the mappers chapter)
- [Great explanation by
  Jamie Barton (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHMaNmqPIC4&list=LL&index=3&ab_channel=JamieBarton)

If you disagree with my conclusions or you have a better understanding of how to handle it feel free to leave a comment

Comment: Wow, that `mappers` bit is such a hidden piece of information!  Thank you so much.  Hours of searching before finally finding your answer here.